# Can an American Indian tribe be a monarchy?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution

The US constitution guarantees States a republican form of government. Does this apply to sovereign American Indian tribes, or could a tribe decide to have a hereditary chieftainship?

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are all hypothetical, but I think its important to add the clear statutory authority on the organization of American Indians, set out in Title 25 U.S.C (Indians):

> **25 U.S.C. § 5123**
> *(a) Adoption; effective date*

> Any Indian tribe shall
> have the right to organize for its common welfare, and may adopt an
> appropriate constitution and bylaws, and any amendments thereto, which
> shall become effective when— (1)ratified by a majority vote of the
> adult members of the tribe or tribes at a special election authorized
> and called by the Secretary under such rules and regulations as the
> Secretary may prescribe; and (2)approved by the Secretary pursuant to
> subsection (d) of this section.

Further down in the same title, we see:

> **25 U.S.C. § 5123(h)Tribal sovereignty**

> Notwithstanding any other provision of this Act—
> (1)each Indian tribe shall retain inherent sovereign power to adopt governing documents under procedures other than those specified in this section; and
> (2)nothing in this Act invalidates any constitution or other governing document adopted by an Indian tribe after June 18, 1934, in accordance with the authority described in paragraph (1).

As we can see, Congress, in exercise of its plenary power, has not altered or changed the inherent sovereign powers of Indian nations to adopt the form of government they so choose, even without approval from the Secretary of the Interior; so long as such government complied with the provisions of the Indian Civil Rights Act, it could have any organization the sovereign tribe found pleasing.  As Indian tribes are sovereign except to the extent limited by Act of Congress made in exercise of Congress's plenary power, they can do whatever they like except where circumscribed (that, after all, is the definition of sovereignty).

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the Bill of Rights is/has to be explicitly encoded as part of Title 25 and is *not* automatically incorporated against tribes, because tribes are *not* states.

Answer (score 0):

The U.S. Constitution would not forbid an Indian tribe recognized by the United States from being organized as a hereditary monarchy, as the applicable limitations on grants of titles of nobility and a Republican form of government, by their terms, apply only to U.S. states and to the federal government. The [Indian Civil Rights Act of 1968](https://www.tribal-institute.org/lists/icra1968.htm) likewise does not expressly rule out the possibility on a hereditary monarchy or hereditary constitutional monarchy in an Indian Tribe (Indian tribes are also not expressly prohibited by the First Amendment to the U.S. Constitution, from establishing a religion, unlike the federal government and the government of U.S. states).

This said, it is not obvious that there might not be other law that could prohibit the practice.

Many provisions of the U.S. Constitution, and of U.S. law, and many treaties between Indian tribes and the United States apply to Indian tribes. Some of these laws and treaties apply to some Indian tribes, but not others.

Members of U.S. Indian tribes are U.S. citizens in addition to being "persons" and so they have the full range of individual constitutional rights that apply to individuals. But the only plausible provision I can imagine to provide political rights within an Indian tribe would be the 14th Amendment's equal protection clause protections. This has been used to determine how political rights in a democratically organized body must be handled, but not to determine if democracy itself is required (because other legal provisions govern that question in U.S. states).

The U.S. Constitution does not require all areas under U.S. legal authority to have democratic government. Historically, some U.S. territories were administered by federally appointed governors without an elected body to advise or constrain the governor. U.S. military bases, scientific bases (e.g. in Antarctica and on a space station), and U.S. embassies are also governed by federal government appointees. Ships on the high seas under U.S. flag are not required to be democratically organized. None of those areas, however, have hereditary monarchies.

Most relevant as a precedent may be the legal status of the former [Queen of Hawaii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lili%CA%BBuokalani) over Native Hawaiians (which is not a legally recognized Indian tribe and so is not exactly on point), which is a somewhat tangled story legally and factually. It is also possible that a hereditary monarch of an Indian tribe could be understood to have an inherited interest in the collective property of the Indian tribe, rather than sovereign authority over the tribe's members (something litigated in the case of Hawaii, where it was held that the Queen's title to property was not private property in the sense of the 5th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution and thus could be seized by the U.S. without just compensation).

I'm not aware of any provision of law that prohibits Indian tribes from being organized as monarchies. But this is a sprawling area of law and I wouldn't be shocked if I was unaware of some applicable authority that required Indian tribes to have democratic self-government as most or all tribes in the U.S. do in practice, or to the contrary, expressly held that this practice was allowed.

Answer (score -3):

Tl;dr Generally speaking, tribes can do whatever they want, as long as they’re not infringing on anyone’s human rights.

Full answer:
Tribes are more or less free to set themselves up however they want. Remember, reservations (almost always) lie outside of a state’s jurisdiction, so it would be difficult to argue that a reservation was infringing on the rights of a state. Furthermore, the U.S. Constitution doesn’t apply to people living on reservations or Indian governments.* Indian tribes can really create whatever form of government they want, since they’re treated as sovereign nations.
That being said, there are *some* rules. Even though they don’t follow most US laws, the federal government can regulate some aspects of reservation life. Perhaps most notably, the Indian Civil Rights Act of 1968 laid out basic rights of all reservation inhabitants. While it doesn’t prevent a monarchy, such a monarchy would still have to have free speech, due process, etc. Moreover, the federal government is responsible for designating which tribal lands are officially recognized. If a monarchy turned into more of a dictatorship and human rights were being violated, the federal government could simply cease to recognize that tribe and its reservation would become part of a state.

As always, Federal Indian Law is incredibly complex and there are many special circumstances, but I hope this gave you a good general overview of Indian self-government. For more information, I highly recommend this site: https://www.uaf.edu/tribal/112/unit_4/generalprinciplesoffederalindianlaw.php

*This a complex matter and part of an ongoing legal debate. See the comments for more info.

Comment: For those users without enough reputation to view the Suggested Edits history, I rejected the proposed deletion of "*Furthermore, the U.S. Constitution doesn’t apply to people living on reservations or Indian governments.*" from this answer.  IMO, the proposer's rationale for the deletion "*The US constitution definitely applies to Indian reservations; look at all the SCOTUS decisions relating to it*" should be raised as a comment and/or as an answer.

Comment: The summary at the beginning of this answer seems to imply that the US constitution _does_ apply to reservations; how else would one determine whether the government of the reservation were infringing on anyone's rights?  How else could the federal government "regulate some aspects of reservation life"?  I'm not downvoting this answer because it makes some good points, but the assessment of the underlying constitutional situation is incorrect.

Comment: I too didn't DV, as I lack knowledge in this area, but I note that the link provided in the answer includes "*The United States Constitution, Bill of Rights, does not apply to the activities of the tribal governments. This is because the sovereign powers of tribes predate the Constitution. Tribal powers come from their own inherent sovereignty and not from the United States Constitution. However, Congress passed the Indian Civil Rights Act in 1968 which applies to all tribes in the United States. The Indian Civil Rights Act is very similar to the U.S. Bill of Rights...*" so, yes: it's complex!

Comment: Treaties between tribes and the US also apply. Generally, the Constitution applies to tribes and their governments. However, if a tribe has a treaty right then any conflict between the treaty and the Constitution would have to be decided by negotiarion or by Federal courts.

Comment: It seems like there are conflicting opinions on the extent to which the Constitution can be applied on reservations. Rather than taking a stance one way or another, I’ll just edit my answer to provide more clarity.